# scroll to top not working, but showing alert

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a scroll to top that i have set an alert when it is clicked on, but it doesn't then animate to the top.

Here is my HTML:

```
<a id="scrollTop"></a>
```

Here is my jquery:

```
$('#scrollTop').click(function(){
    alert('hello');
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
    return false;
```

And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7hxrb/) is a link a fiddle. Scroll down to the bottom to see the grey box.

Comment: How about setting up a demo, such as jsfiddle where we can edit and help you realtime?

Comment: Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7hxrb/

Comment: OK here is the working version: http://jsfiddle.net/7hxrb/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, your HTML and body elements have a scrollTop value of zero, despite where you are on the page.

Try animating scrollTop on the '#mainContent' element:

```
$('#scrollTop').click(function(){
    alert('hello');
    $('#mainContent').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
    return false;
});
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: His <body> has an height of 0!, +1 for the solution

Answer (score -1):

I see that the bootstrap.min.js is not loaded.

Comment: Why does he need bootstrap?

Comment: He didn't, i expected that it would lead to a problem with his click function.